# OrmLite Condition with Nullable DateTime and DateAdd

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to accomplish

`SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EnrollmentDate > DATEADD(Month, 1, HireDate)`

Unfortunately `HireDate` is nullable, and thus OrmLite will fail to generate this query.

```
var query = db.From<Employee>()
    .Where(employee => employee.EnrollmentDate > employee.HireDate.Value.AddMonths(1))
);
```

I have tried using which still fails

```
.Where(employee => employee.HireDate.HasValue && employee.EnrollmentDate > employee.HireDate.Value.AddMonths(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found out the it's failing in

> ServiceStack.OrmLite
>
> SqlExpression.GetQuotedColumnName(ModelDefinition tableDef, string memberName)

(see image)

This fails with "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
using (var db = _stagingConnectionFactory.Open())
{
    var query = db.From<tblActivityImportCalculationQueue>();

    query = query.Where(i => 
        (DateTime.Now - i.LastUpdated.Value).TotalMinutes > 30
    );

    query.ToMergedParamsSelectStatement();
}
```

The solution for me until the bug is fixed in OrmLite is using plain sql

```
using (var db = _stagingConnectionFactory.Open())
{
    var query = db.From<tblActivityImportCalculationQueue>();

    query = query.Where("DATEDIFF(minute, LastUpdated, GETDATE()) > 30");

    query.ToMergedParamsSelectStatement();
}
```

[image: tableDef is null]

Comment: that's pretty much what my resolution was as well, I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve using raw sql